# CSS Radio Button Buttons wraps label text upwards and moves the block with it

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I am trying to create a list of buttons from modified radio button. However, as soon as the label becomes 2 liner, the block goes up with the label. This is my css code:

```
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] {
  display:none;
}

.radio-toolbar label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fff;
  color:#999;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px rgba(204,204,204,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px rgba(204,204,204,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px rgba(204,204,204,0.75);
}

.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #00aaa7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #00aaa7;
  color:#fff;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px rgba(0,170,167,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px rgba(0,170,167,1);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px rgba(0,170,167,1);
}


<div class="radio-toolbar margin-top" ng-repeat="physical in physicals">
  <span class="medium-font fw300 dark-gray">{{ physical.name }}</span><br>
  <span ng-repeat="condition in physical.conditions">
    <input ng-click="physicalExam($parent.$index, physical, condition)" type="radio" name="{{ physical.name }}" id="{{ condition._id }}" value="{{ condition.conditionName }}">
    <label class="small-font fw300 gray" for="{{ condition._id }}">{{ condition.conditionName }}</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

See [JFFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bddswtth/2/).

Comment: please provide jsfiddle of it!

Comment: Create a [mcve]. What you posted is neither complete, nor verifiable. You can add angular.js to your snippet. And if you don't want to include your whole application, just make a dummy controller with a dump of your `physical.conditions`. Or even, just copy-paste the parsed html.

Comment: We need to some rendered html - we can't guess what `Angular` or whatever you're using will spit out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.radio-toolbar label { 
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

<kbd>[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/bddswtth/3/)</kbd>